# Javascript behaviour difference between IE and Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, firefox, internet-explorer

I have the following code which should update a label to say "please wait..", then run a function, and then update the label again to say it has completed:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload"
                    onclientclick="document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerText='Please Wait...';" 
                    onclick="Button1_Click"  />
```

This works fine in IE, but not in Firefox.

When I run it in Firefox the label does not change until the process completes.

Is there a way to force the javascript to update the page before running the C# function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `innerText` property is a proprietary Internet Explorer feature.  In Firefox and other DOM compatible browsers, use `textContent`([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent)).

The following code will test to see which property is supported by the browser and use the appropriate one:

```
var node = document.getElementById('errorMessage');
var errorMessage = 'Please Wait...';
if (typeof node.innerText !== 'undefined')
  node.innerText = errorMessage;
else
  node.textContent = errorMessage;
```

If your site will involve a lot of JavaScript, I strongly recommend using a 3rd-party library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) that takes care of these browser incompatibilities for you.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try:

```
document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = 'Please Wait...'
```

And to avoid putting different code in different browsers, i'd suggest you to use jQuery.

```
$('#errorMessage').html('Please Wait...');
```

Answer (score 2):

`onclientclick` and `innerText` are not standard DOM attributes. Use `onclick` and `textContent` or `innerHTML`. Or better yet, use jQuery:

```
$('#Button1').click(function() {
    $('#errorMessage').text('Please Wait...');
});
```

Comment: `onclientclick` is a property of the ASP.NET Button class.  Server-side processing turns it into `onclick` in the resulting page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with standard DOM methods rather the non-standard (and subtly different) `innerText` and `textContent` properties:

```
var el = document.getElementById('errorMessage');
while (el.firstChild) {
    el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
}
el.appendChild( document.createTextNode('Please Wait...') );
```

Obviously this is quite verbose, and is likely to be slower than the `innerHTML` alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the behavior of JavaScript does very in some details across different browsers.  Here's my suggestion:  use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

The experts at jQuery have done tremendous work to smooth over these differences, and many other pitfalls besides.